# How do you find the number of leaves at the lowest level of a complete binary tree?

Tags: binary-tree

I'm trying to define an algorithm that returns the number of leaves at the lowest level of a complete binary tree. By a complete binary tree, I mean *a binary tree whose every level, except possibly the last, is filled, and all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible.*

For example, if I had the following complete binary tree,

```
      _ 7_
    /      \
   4        9
  / \     / \
 2   6   8   10
/ \  /
1  3 5
```

the algorithm would return '3' since there are three leaves at the lowest level of the tree.

I've been able to find numerous solutions for finding the count of all the leaves in *regular or balanced* binary trees, but so far I haven't had any luck with the particular case of finding the count of the leaves *at the lowest level* of a *complete* binary tree. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a breadth-first search, so you can aswell find a number of nodes on each level.

Some pseudo code

```
q <- new queue of (node, level) data
add (root, 0) in q

nodesPerLevel <- new vector of integers 

while q is not empty:
    (currentNode, currentLevel) <- take from top of q
    nodesPerLevel[currentLevel] += 1
    for each child in currentNode's children: 
        add (child, currentLevel + 1) in q

return last value of nodesPerLevel
```